# SQL - need to return a value of 0 or 1 based on items in a list

Tags: sql-server, xml, xslt-1.0

Based on the type of employee in a table I need to return a 0 or 1 to then be output to specific spot in a file

For EXB return 1 for all other types FTR, FTRG, PTRG and SALR return 0.

Comment: To be more explicit about the cases you know: `case when [Type] = 'EXB' then 1 when [Type] in ( 'FTR', 'FTRG', 'PTRG', 'SALR' ) then 0 else NULL end`. `NULL` is the default result if there is no match, but you can explicitly include it in an `ELSE`.

Answer (score 5):

```
select case when type = 'EXB' then 1 else 0 end
from employee
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `case <column> when 'EXB' then 1 else 0 end` as shown in the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/137c8e/8) to select values in the expression query.

Alternately, use a lookup table to map from your codes to the numeric values.

Then use one of the XML modifiers in the query to return an xml fragment.